# Align range vertically

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a [vis.js](/questions/tagged/vis.js) timeline and I'd like to align the ranges so it'll be displayed on two lines instead of 4.

I can't find the option that would allow me to do that, I've tried with `stack: false` but *all* the ranges are stacked and I lose visibility on the different ranges.

Can I achieve that? If yes, how?

Here's what I have now:

```js
var groups = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 2, content: 'Foo'}
  ]);

  var id = 0;

  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: id++, content: 'Charles',                  className:'bg-success', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T18:00:00', end: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', group: 2},
    {id: id++, content: '',                  className:'bg-danger', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T18:00:00', end: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', group: 2},
    {id: id++, content: 'Flavie, Vincent',          className:'bg-warning', editable: { updateTime: true, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', end: '2018-02-14T08:00:00', group: 2},
    {id: id++, content: 'Nathan',                   className:'bg-success', editable: { updateTime: true, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', end: '2018-02-14T08:00:00', group: 2},
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var options = {
    editable: true,
    zoomable : false,
    start: new Date(2018,1,13,12,0,0),
    end: new Date(2018,1,14),
  };

  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
```

And here's what I'd like to get: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack: false` is a correct option, but also you need to `group` (or `subgroup`) your items correctly. See the snippet below:

```js
var options = {
    stack: false,
    editable: true,
    zoomable : false,
    start: new Date(2018,1,13,12,0,0),
    end: new Date(2018,1,14),
};

var groups = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'Bar'},
    {id: 2, content: 'Foo'}
]);

var id = 0;

var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: id++, content: '', className:'bg-danger', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T18:00:00', end: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', group: 1},
    {id: id++, content: 'Nathan', className:'bg-success', editable: { updateTime: true, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', end: '2018-02-14T08:00:00', group: 1},
    {id: id++, content: 'Charles', className:'bg-success', editable: { updateTime: false, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T18:00:00', end: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', group: 2},
    {id: id++, content: 'Flavie, Vincent', className:'bg-warning', editable: { updateTime: true, updateGroup: true, remove: false }, start: '2018-02-13T20:00:00', end: '2018-02-14T08:00:00', group: 2},
]);

var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
```